# memory occupied by set vs frozenset in Python 2.7

Tags: python, memory, set, size, immutability

I was recently comparing the amount of memory occupied by a Python `set` to that occupied by a `frozenset` using [Pympler](http://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/%20Pympler):

```
>>> from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
>>> x = range(100)
>>> s = set(x)
>>> f0 = frozenset(x)
>>> f1 = frozenset(s)
>>> asizeof(s)
10824
>>> asizeof(f0)
10824
>>> asizeof(f1)
6728
>>> f0==f1
True
```

Why would a `frozenset` created from a `set` occupy a different amount of memory than one created from some other iterable? Or is this just a quirk of how Pympler approximates the amount of memory occupied by a variable in Python?

Comment: Similar behavior observed with Python 3.4.0.

Comment: Related: `frozenset` also doesn't get allocated by `PyObject_Malloc`, so most memory trackers (`pympler`, `tracemalloc`) cannot see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the frozenset constructor logic in C, but it's indeed possibly worth a CPython bug report.

Comment: Could it be `f1` internally references `s` and therefore doesn't allocate extra memory like `f0` does?

Comment: Interesting discovery and good question (+1) but **Note to future readers**, the issue was reviewed and rejected (twice, it appears). It's intended to be this way (for a reasonable reason, IMVHO). Read the issue comments to understand their reasons.